# Astigmatism - streaks through light

Tags: optics, everyday-life, vision

Why do I see lines or streaks through light, say, for example, the headlights of a car? Is the eye defect curable? I usually don't see it during the day, unless I kinda partially close my eyes so that I can only see through my eyelashes. Then, the vision becomes watery and blurred, and I can see these streaks again, reflected from some surface or the sunlight through the window...

Comment: Why do you not just see an ey doctor , who can tell you if anything is wrong with your ey, and what to do about it. this is not a physics question.

Comment: Due to lockdown (because of coronavirus) I really can't, and online appointments are just a waste of money. This is very common and I am sure someone would know more about it @trula